# Weyl sequence for closure of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve following exercise and need some hints.

Let $A= \bar{ A_0 }$ be closure of $A_0$ - a densely defined operator. Suppose $f_n \in D(A)$ is Weyl sequence for $z \in \sigma (A)$. Show that there exists a Weyl sequence in $D(A_0)$.

For reference I include definition of Weyl sequence:

$\psi _n \in D(A)$ is Weyl sequence for $z \in \mathbb C$ if $ \| \psi _n \| = 1 $ and $(A-z) \psi _n \to 0$.

I tried approximating terms of Weyl sequence by elements of unit norm in $D(A_0)$ (since it's dense) but I don't know anything about continuity of $A$ so it doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Should not $\psi_n$ converge weakly to zero for being Weyl sequence?

Comment: Book that I use ("Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics with applications to Schrödinger Operators" by Gerald Teschl) explicitly mentions strong convergence in definition given and that is where the exercise comes from so I suppose they are compatible. It might be that it is not most general approach as the book is intended for physics students interested in getting to mathematically rigourous QM as fast as possible. I will look it up in some different sources later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $z=0$ (otherwise apply the proof to the operator $A-z$ instead). The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is Weyl, i.e. $\|f_n\|=1$ and $\|Af_n\|\to 0$ when $n\to+\infty$.

1. The vector $(f_n,Af_n)$ belongs to the graph $\Gamma(A)$. Since $A=\bar A_0$ we know that $\Gamma(A)=\bar\Gamma(A_0)$, so we can approximate $(f_n,Af_n)$ arbitrary well by $(g_n,A_0g_n)$ with $g_n\in D(A_0)$ in the graph metric, for example, as
   $$
   \|f_n-g_n\|^2+\|Af_n-A_0g_n\|^2\le\frac{1}{n^2}
   $$
   which implies, in particular, that $\|f_n-g_n\|\le\frac1n$ and $\|Af_n-A_0g_n\|\le\frac{1}{n}$.
2. By the reverse triangle inequality we have 
   $$
   0\le\Big|1-\|g_n\|\Big|=\Big|\|f_n\|-\|g_n\|\Big|\le\|f_n-g_n\|\le\frac1n\to 0,
   $$
   therefore, $\|g_n\|\to 1$ as $n\to+\infty$. Moreover,
   $$
   0\le\|A_0g_n\|=\|A_0g_n-Af_n+Af_n\|\le \|A_0g_n-Af_n\|+\|Af_n\|\le\frac1n+\|Af_n\|\to 0.
   $$
3. Let us show that $\psi_n=\frac{g_n}{\|g_n\|}\in D(A_0)$ is the Weyl sequence. Indeed, $\|\psi_n\|=1$ and
   $$
   \|A_0\psi_n\|=\frac{\|A_0g_n\|}{\|g_n\|}\to\frac{0}{1}=0.
   $$

Comment: @A.$\Gamma$ can you help me to construct a Weyl sequence for the operator $-\Delta_{\Bbb{R}^2}-x^2-y^2$.